# pacemaker won't start because duplicate node but can't remove dupe node because pacemaker won't start

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, pacemaker, corosync

OK! Really new to pacemaker/corosync, like 1 day new.

Software: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the versions associated with that distro.

pacemakerd: 1.1.18

corosync: 2.4.3

I accidentally removed the nodes from my entire test cluster (3 nodes)

When I tried to bring everything back up using `pcsd` GUI, that failed because the nodes were "wiped out". Cool.

So. I had a copy of the last `corosync.conf` from my "primary" node. I copied to the other two nodes. I fixed the `bindnetaddr` on the respective confs. I ran `pcs cluster start` on my "primary" node.

One of the nodes failed to come up. I took a look at the status of `pacemaker` on that node and I get the following exception:

```
Dec 18 06:33:56 region-ctrl-2 crmd[1049]:     crit: Nodes 1084777441 and 2 share the same name 'region-ctrl-2': shutting down
```

I tried running `crm_node -R --force 1084777441` on the machine where `pacemaker` won't start, but of course, `pacemaker` isn't running so I get an `crmd: connection refused (111)` error. So, I ran the same command on one of the healthy nodes, which shows no errors, but the node never goes away and `pacemaker` on the affected machine continued to show the same error.

So, I decided to tear down the entire cluster and again. I purge removed all the packages from the machine. I reinstalled everything fresh. I copied and fixed the `corosync.conf` to the machine. I recreated the cluster. I get the exact same bloody error.

So this node named `1084777441` is not a machine I created. This is one the cluster created for me. Earlier in the day I realized that I was using IP addresses in `corosync.conf` instead of names. I fixed the `/etc/hosts` of the machines, removed the IP addresses from the corosync config, and that's why I inadvertently deleted my whole cluster in the first place (I removed the nodes that were IP addresses).

The following is my corosync.conf:

```
totem {
    version: 2
    cluster_name: maas-cluster
    token: 3000
    token_retransmits_before_loss_const: 10
    clear_node_high_bit: yes
    crypto_cipher: none
    crypto_hash: none

    interface {
        ringnumber: 0
        bindnetaddr: 192.168.99.225
        mcastport: 5405
        ttl: 1
    }
}

logging {
    fileline: off
    to_stderr: no
    to_logfile: no
    to_syslog: yes
    syslog_facility: daemon
    debug: off
    timestamp: on

    logger_subsys {
        subsys: QUORUM
        debug: off
    }
}

quorum {
    provider: corosync_votequorum
    expected_votes: 3
    two_node: 1
}

nodelist {
    node {
        ring0_addr: postgres-sb
        nodeid: 3
    }

    node {
        ring0_addr: region-ctrl-2
        nodeid: 2
    }

    node {
        ring0_addr: region-ctrl-1
        nodeid: 1
    }
}
```

The only thing different about this conf between the nodes is the `bindnetaddr`.

There seems to be a chicken/egg issue here unless there's some way of which I'm not aware to remove a node from a flat-file db or sqlite dbb somewhere or there's some other more authoritative way to remove a node from a cluster.

**ADDITIONAL**

I've made sure that `/etc/hosts` and the hostname of each of the machines match. I forgot to mention that.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 postgres
192.168.99.224 postgres-sb
192.168.99.223 region-ctrl-1
192.168.99.225 region-ctrl-2

192.168.7.224 postgres-sb
192.168.7.223 region-ctrl-1
192.168.7.225 region-ctrl-2


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I decided to try to start from scratch. I `apt removed --purge`ed `corosync*`, `pacemaker*` `crmsh`, and `pcs`. I `rm -rf`ed `/etc/corosync`. I kept a copy of the `corosync.conf` on each machine.

I re-installed all the things on each of the machines. I copied my saved `corosync.conf` to `/etc/corosync/` and restarted `corosync` on all the machines.

I *STILL* get the same exact error. This has to be a bug in one of the components!

So it seems that `crm_get_peer` is failing to recognize that the host named `region-ctrl-2` is assigned nodeid 2 in `corosync.conf`. Node 2 then get auto-assigned an ID of 1084777441. This is the part that doesn't make sense to me. The hostname of the machine is `region-ctrl-2` set in `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` and confirmed using `uname -n`. The `corosync.conf` is explicitly assigning an ID to the machine named `region-ctrl-2` but something is apparently not recognizing the assignment from `corosync` and instead assigned a non-randomized ID with the value 1084777441 to this host. How the freak do I fix this?

**LOGS**

```
    info: crm_log_init: Changed active directory to /var/lib/pacemaker/cores
    info: get_cluster_type:     Detected an active 'corosync' cluster
    info: qb_ipcs_us_publish:   server name: pacemakerd
    info: pcmk__ipc_is_authentic_process_active:        Could not connect to lrmd IPC: Connection refused
    info: pcmk__ipc_is_authentic_process_active:        Could not connect to cib_ro IPC: Connection refused
    info: pcmk__ipc_is_authentic_process_active:        Could not connect to crmd IPC: Connection refused
    info: pcmk__ipc_is_authentic_process_active:        Could not connect to attrd IPC: Connection refused
    info: pcmk__ipc_is_authentic_process_active:        Could not connect to pengine IPC: Connection refused
    info: pcmk__ipc_is_authentic_process_active:        Could not connect to stonith-ng IPC: Connection refused
    info: corosync_node_name:   Unable to get node name for nodeid 1084777441
  notice: get_node_name:        Could not obtain a node name for corosync nodeid 1084777441
    info: crm_get_peer: Created entry ea4ec23e-e676-4798-9b8b-00af39d3bb3d/0x5555f74984d0 for node (null)/1084777441 (1 total)
    info: crm_get_peer: Node 1084777441 has uuid 1084777441
    info: crm_update_peer_proc: cluster_connect_cpg: Node (null)[1084777441] - corosync-cpg is now online
  notice: cluster_connect_quorum:       Quorum acquired
    info: crm_get_peer: Created entry 882c0feb-d546-44b7-955f-4c8a844a0db1/0x5555f7499fd0 for node postgres-sb/3 (2 total)
    info: crm_get_peer: Node 3 is now known as postgres-sb
    info: crm_get_peer: Node 3 has uuid 3
    info: crm_get_peer: Created entry 4e6a6b1e-d687-4527-bffc-5d701ff60a66/0x5555f749a6f0 for node region-ctrl-2/2 (3 total)
    info: crm_get_peer: Node 2 is now known as region-ctrl-2
    info: crm_get_peer: Node 2 has uuid 2
    info: crm_get_peer: Created entry 5532a3cc-2577-4764-b9ee-770d437ccec0/0x5555f749a0a0 for node region-ctrl-1/1 (4 total)
    info: crm_get_peer: Node 1 is now known as region-ctrl-1
    info: crm_get_peer: Node 1 has uuid 1
    info: corosync_node_name:   Unable to get node name for nodeid 1084777441
  notice: get_node_name:        Defaulting to uname -n for the local corosync node name
 warning: crm_find_peer:        Node 1084777441 and 2 share the same name: 'region-ctrl-2'
    info: crm_get_peer: Node 1084777441 is now known as region-ctrl-2
    info: pcmk_quorum_notification:     Quorum retained | membership=32 members=3
  notice: crm_update_peer_state_iter:   Node region-ctrl-1 state is now member | nodeid=1 previous=unknown source=pcmk_quorum_notification
  notice: crm_update_peer_state_iter:   Node postgres-sb state is now member | nodeid=3 previous=unknown source=pcmk_quorum_notification
  notice: crm_update_peer_state_iter:   Node region-ctrl-2 state is now member | nodeid=1084777441 previous=unknown source=pcmk_quorum_notification
    info: crm_reap_unseen_nodes:        State of node region-ctrl-2[2] is still unknown
    info: pcmk_cpg_membership:  Node 1084777441 joined group pacemakerd (counter=0.0, pid=32765, unchecked for rivals)
    info: pcmk_cpg_membership:  Node 1 still member of group pacemakerd (peer=region-ctrl-1:900, counter=0.0, at least once)
    info: crm_update_peer_proc: pcmk_cpg_membership: Node region-ctrl-1[1] - corosync-cpg is now online
    info: pcmk_cpg_membership:  Node 3 still member of group pacemakerd (peer=postgres-sb:976, counter=0.1, at least once)
    info: crm_update_peer_proc: pcmk_cpg_membership: Node postgres-sb[3] - corosync-cpg is now online
    info: pcmk_cpg_membership:  Node 1084777441 still member of group pacemakerd (peer=region-ctrl-2:3016, counter=0.2, at least once)
  pengine:     info: crm_log_init:      Changed active directory to /var/lib/pacemaker/cores
     lrmd:     info: crm_log_init:      Changed active directory to /var/lib/pacemaker/cores
     lrmd:     info: qb_ipcs_us_publish:        server name: lrmd
  pengine:     info: qb_ipcs_us_publish:        server name: pengine
      cib:     info: crm_log_init:      Changed active directory to /var/lib/pacemaker/cores
    attrd:     info: crm_log_init:      Changed active directory to /var/lib/pacemaker/cores
    attrd:     info: get_cluster_type:  Verifying cluster type: 'corosync'
    attrd:     info: get_cluster_type:  Assuming an active 'corosync' cluster
    info: crm_log_init: Changed active directory to /var/lib/pacemaker/cores
    attrd:   notice: crm_cluster_connect:       Connecting to cluster infrastructure: corosync
      cib:     info: get_cluster_type:  Verifying cluster type: 'corosync'
      cib:     info: get_cluster_type:  Assuming an active 'corosync' cluster
    info: get_cluster_type:     Verifying cluster type: 'corosync'
    info: get_cluster_type:     Assuming an active 'corosync' cluster
  notice: crm_cluster_connect:  Connecting to cluster infrastructure: corosync
    attrd:     info: corosync_node_name:        Unable to get node name for nodeid 1084777441
      cib:     info: validate_with_relaxng:     Creating RNG parser context
     crmd:     info: crm_log_init:      Changed active directory to /var/lib/pacemaker/cores
     crmd:     info: get_cluster_type:  Verifying cluster type: 'corosync'
     crmd:     info: get_cluster_type:  Assuming an active 'corosync' cluster
     crmd:     info: do_log:    Input I_STARTUP received in state S_STARTING from crmd_init
    attrd:   notice: get_node_name:     Could not obtain a node name for corosync nodeid 1084777441
    attrd:     info: crm_get_peer:      Created entry af5c62c9-21c5-4428-9504-ea72a92de7eb/0x560870420e90 for node (null)/1084777441 (1 total)
    attrd:     info: crm_get_peer:      Node 1084777441 has uuid 1084777441
    attrd:     info: crm_update_peer_proc:      cluster_connect_cpg: Node (null)[1084777441] - corosync-cpg is now online
    attrd:   notice: crm_update_peer_state_iter:        Node (null) state is now member | nodeid=1084777441 previous=unknown source=crm_update_peer_proc
    attrd:     info: init_cs_connection_once:   Connection to 'corosync': established
    info: corosync_node_name:   Unable to get node name for nodeid 1084777441
  notice: get_node_name:        Could not obtain a node name for corosync nodeid 1084777441
    info: crm_get_peer: Created entry 5bcb51ae-0015-4652-b036-b92cf4f1d990/0x55f583634700 for node (null)/1084777441 (1 total)
    info: crm_get_peer: Node 1084777441 has uuid 1084777441
    info: crm_update_peer_proc: cluster_connect_cpg: Node (null)[1084777441] - corosync-cpg is now online
  notice: crm_update_peer_state_iter:   Node (null) state is now member | nodeid=1084777441 previous=unknown source=crm_update_peer_proc
    attrd:     info: corosync_node_name:        Unable to get node name for nodeid 1084777441
    attrd:   notice: get_node_name:     Defaulting to uname -n for the local corosync node name
    attrd:     info: crm_get_peer:      Node 1084777441 is now known as region-ctrl-2
    info: corosync_node_name:   Unable to get node name for nodeid 1084777441
  notice: get_node_name:        Defaulting to uname -n for the local corosync node name
    info: init_cs_connection_once:      Connection to 'corosync': established
    info: corosync_node_name:   Unable to get node name for nodeid 1084777441
  notice: get_node_name:        Defaulting to uname -n for the local corosync node name
    info: crm_get_peer: Node 1084777441 is now known as region-ctrl-2
      cib:   notice: crm_cluster_connect:       Connecting to cluster infrastructure: corosync
      cib:     info: corosync_node_name:        Unable to get node name for nodeid 1084777441
      cib:   notice: get_node_name:     Could not obtain a node name for corosync nodeid 1084777441
      cib:     info: crm_get_peer:      Created entry a6ced2c1-9d51-445d-9411-2fb19deab861/0x55848365a150 for node (null)/1084777441 (1 total)
      cib:     info: crm_get_peer:      Node 1084777441 has uuid 1084777441
      cib:     info: crm_update_peer_proc:      cluster_connect_cpg: Node (null)[1084777441] - corosync-cpg is now online
      cib:   notice: crm_update_peer_state_iter:        Node (null) state is now member | nodeid=1084777441 previous=unknown source=crm_update_peer_proc
      cib:     info: init_cs_connection_once:   Connection to 'corosync': established
      cib:     info: corosync_node_name:        Unable to get node name for nodeid 1084777441
      cib:   notice: get_node_name:     Defaulting to uname -n for the local corosync node name
      cib:     info: crm_get_peer:      Node 1084777441 is now known as region-ctrl-2
      cib:     info: qb_ipcs_us_publish:        server name: cib_ro
      cib:     info: qb_ipcs_us_publish:        server name: cib_rw
      cib:     info: qb_ipcs_us_publish:        server name: cib_shm
      cib:     info: pcmk_cpg_membership:       Node 1084777441 joined group cib (counter=0.0, pid=0, unchecked for rivals)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with clusterlabs a bit, I was able to find a fix for this. The fix was fix `/etc/corosync/corosync.conf` by adding `transport: udpu` in the `totem` directive and to making sure all nodes are properly added in the `nodelist` directive. If using nodes by name only then one needs to make sure that the nodes are properly resolvable which is done usually in `/etc/hosts`. Once the `corosync.conf` is fixed, restart the entire cluster. In my case, the following `corosync.conf` was the fixed version:

```
totem {
    version: 2
    cluster_name: maas-cluster
    token: 3000
    token_retransmits_before_loss_const: 10
    clear_node_high_bit: yes
    crypto_cipher: none
    crypto_hash: none
    transport: udpu

    interface {
        ringnumber: 0
        bindnetaddr: 192.168.99.0
        mcastport: 5405
        ttl: 1
    }
}

logging {
    fileline: off
    to_stderr: no
    to_logfile: no
    to_syslog: yes
    syslog_facility: daemon
    debug: off
    timestamp: on

    logger_subsys {
        subsys: QUORUM
        debug: off
    }
}

quorum {
    provider: corosync_votequorum
    expected_votes: 3
    two_node: 1
}

nodelist {
    node {
        ring0_addr: postgres-sb
        nodeid: 3
    }

    node {
        ring0_addr: region-ctrl-2
        nodeid: 2
    }

    node {
        ring0_addr: region-ctrl-1
        nodeid: 1
    }
}
```